# Why does AES return different encryption?

Tags: python, hash, aes, hash-function

Here is my Python code (but the question is probably not unique to Python). The ciphertext is different every time, with initialization vector fixed.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

cipher = AES.new(b'Sixteen byte key', AES.MODE_CFB, iv=b'16 bytes long iv')
for i in range(3):
    print(cipher.encrypt(b'data'))
```

which returns

```
b',=ng'
b'\xedK\xd3\xec'
b'\xbd\x82\xed\n'
```

1. Why does it return different ciphertext? Maybe I'm not supposed to encrypt multiple times with the same cipher?
2. I basically need to use AES as a hash function, i.e., encrypt the same plaintext multiple times and get the same result. Is there a good way to do so?

Comment: 1. You answered that yourself 2. AES is not a cryptographic hash function and you should not expect any security from it if abused as one.

Comment: When encrypting 3 blocks on the same cipher instance you are getting three different output blocks. That is by design of the [CFB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_(CFB)). If you want the same result you need to recreate or reset the AES cipher object. For hashing via AES you should use a AES-MAC implementation.